# using DrawerLayout with same content_pane

Tags: android, android-layout

Friends I am newbie to android...

**Scenario**
I am using a drawerLayout to use a slider menu in my app... But as described in the general android developer guide I don't want to change the content_frame based on the click in the slider menu view... but the content_frame is going to stay and only the information will be changing..so it will be based on the updated data based on the action selected in the slider menu.

**What is happening now:**
I am using the same sample and using the below code(1) and defining my main view layout in a file as content_frame.xml but it is not working I am getting a blank window... instead I am defining the same layout into the same FrameLayout as shown below code(2), but I am not able to properly arrange the components in it.. and I could see from different places as it is a dirty coding approach...

**What I need to do** 
I need to link the layout file for my main view to this frameLayout so that I can use the DrawerLayout and the slider menu in my app.

Please help me with the possibilities in android for doing this..

Thanks for your time and effort...

**(1)Example code from developer guide**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**(2)My code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
         />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
         />


    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->


    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#fff"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to have a single layout file for both your content and the drawer and you will not be using a fragment for your content.

To achieve this all you have to do is define your content's layout as the first child of a DrawerLayout view, and the drawer's layout as the second, as you have done in your example.

The thing is those views don't have to be FrameLayout and ListView as in the example, they can be anything you want.

For example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />   


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/dl_left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_TextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer_TextView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/dl_left_drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here you can see both the content and the drawer are Linear Layouts, although they can be whatever you want.

*EDIT*:

you can also include your main content view if you have it in a seperate file (for example main_content.xml) by using `<include layout="@layout/main_content"/>` instead of the first `<LinearLayout >.... </LinearLayout>`

for more info :
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Comment: thanks.. let me try and will let you know... @Evripidis